# ngStyle with a function call not working in IE

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ng-style

in an angular 4 application i have styles like below

```
[ngStyle]="{'border': getInterleaveColor(i)}"
```

and the function

```
 getInterleaveColor(auditNumber) {
    var borderProperties = '2px solid';
    if (auditNumber % 2 == 0)
        return borderProperties + '#0078D2';
    else
        return borderProperties + '#00B989';
}
```

is working fine in chrome but not working in IE.

Comment: does it work if you add a space before the color? `return borderProperties + 
' #0078D2'`. This way solid & the hex code aren't a single string

Comment: missing a space after solid

Comment: it was a space issue :( . put is as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space after solid so `solid` and the `hex color` are not a single string

```
var borderProperties = '2px solid ';
```